# File format for storing html parser rules

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse a page which structure changes over time. For now the parsing config is written in Java so I have to issue a new build each time the rules get modified.
Is there some sort of json- or xml-based markup language I could use to store the parsing config in an external file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options include XPath and CSS selectors syntax. The latter is supported by Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Clojure , Clojure can represent your config data and call Jsoup for parse