# Extensible HTML parsing in Java driven by decoupled rules

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing, jsoup

We are using the awesome jsoup library to parse HTML documents in Java.

Now the source of these documents differ (they are coming from different clients), so the HTML elements and the text differ per different source. To handle this we have written a separate HTML parser per different source of HTML document that deals with elements, element text, element attributes etc. of that document. Some of the parsed text needs to be replaced etc as well.

The stuff is working but indeed it is not extensible. We have to write a new HTML parser for a new html document source or add/change code of an existing one if there are more elements added or removed from the supported HTML document.

E.g if today the parser for a document from company ExampleCompany expects us to parse their HTML and process it with the following 2 element attributes:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlAsString);
String dataExampleCount = doc.select("div[id=top-share-bar]").attr("data-example_count");
String cbDateText = doc.select("div[class=cbdate]").text();
```

Tomorrow, the ExampleCompany adds a new element to their HTML (it may be in JavaScript or CSS or in the body) like "a[class=loc mr10]" and expects us to use that element's text as well. So we have to go and add another line of code:

```
String locMr10Text = doc.select("a[class=loc mr10]").text();
```

Is there a way to decouple the rules or XPATH expressions to find the elements and their text in some external file, be it XML or JSON or XSL where I can just define which elements to be looked for, which element's attributes or text to be extracted etc?

So, from the above example, if I externalize the rules in JSON:

```
{
    "Attrs": {
        "div[id=top-share-bar]": "data-example_count",
        },
    "Text": '[
        "div[class=cbdate]",
        "div[class=loc mr10]",
        ]'
}
```

We could just keep updating the rules JSON and not add any line of Java code but Just parse the JSON and accordingly parse the HTML.

This will facilitate in:

- There will be only 1 HTML parser which just takes the rules and the
  HTML document and produces the output.
- No need to recompile the code
  if the HTML document's elements change. Just change the rules file to
  accommodate the change.

I am thinking of writing our own format to externalize the XPATH expressions etc but wished to know if there is something standard being used if there is a requirement like ours.

I have read a related link to what I am asking [File format for storing html parser rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533989/file-format-for-storing-html-parser-rules), however I am not sure if the answer gives any direction of best way of decoupling the what to parse from how to parse it.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Not really clear to me why you are rewriting your HTML parser every time the input document changes. Parsing a document should be independent of selecting parts of it or manipulating it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I have updated the original post to give an example.

Comment: You can use Xsoup if you want to use XPATH instead of css selectors

Comment: @alkis - XSoup is an HTML cleaner/ sanitizer that uses JSoup. That is not what I am asking. I would like to decouple the XPATH expressions or CSS selectors into a schema rather than hard-coding in the code. This will facilitate in writing a generic parser that can take any schema and parse an HTML document.

Comment: What you need can be accomplished with 
1. properties file (key-value) 
2. xml file (with an xsd if you want to have specific rules about the xml) and use JAXB for parsing it and feeding it to jsoup.
3. json file as you said, although I would recommend xml, it's more readable for these kind of things, and you have xsd in order to specify specific rules about the structure of the xml. But still I don't understand the problem, since you have an idea of what you want. What are you asking exactly? Implementation, code example, tools?

Comment: @alkis - Thanks for the response. I am not looking for code. I am looking for some guidelines if someone has already done this then which format of keeping the metadata, in this case the XPATH expressions, would be most efficient and flexible. Any issues later on etc.You did talk about those ways in your last comment which I knew - like using XML and JAXB but wanted to know if there are any better. Anyway, I am almost done by using JSON Schemas using JACKSON.

Comment: I don't believe you will face any problems. Please post an answer describing your solution for future reference and of course, if no one else answers, accept it too.

Comment: You could write your own rule parser and make a generic code which users variables in the selectors rather than literals. Just an idea, I'm in the design phase of a software like yours, and thats our worst case scenario by now, unless some coder knows a better way